# How to random position of TextView by programming

Tags: android, textview

I would like to randomly the Android:Text and Android:id in TexTView by programe as the Layout Bellow

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/drag"
android:layout_below="@+id/color_score"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/1"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/choice_drag"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/2"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/1"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:text="2"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/choice_drag"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/3"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/2"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:text="3"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/choice_drag"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/4"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/3"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:text="4"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/choice_drag"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/5"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/4"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:text="5"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/choice_drag"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to randomly when start activity the position of TextView alway change location.
Example I will have 3 times to start Activity:

```
1st start activity : TextView ID and Text, will range as (1,2,3,4,5)
2nd start activity : TextView ID and Text, will range as (2,4,5,1,3)
3rd start activity : TextView ID and Text, will range as (4,5,1,2,3)
```

Any method to do this way?

Please!

Comment: there are exactly 120 combinations of **1,2,3,4,5**. you could cache them in an array(probably int) and then choose one at random, then arrange your views in that way. here's a good permutation generator: http://textmechanic.com/Permutation-Generator.html

Comment: or he could just generate them at runtime